# Calculation in Python or SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am a data analyst in finance world so we always need to do a lot of calculations in Excel. E.g. calculating Debt to Equity ratio, Sales % of Revenue, etc. In Excel is pretty easy to write formula but we want to have these calculations in our SQL database so that we can push these results to the dashboard. One way I was doing this is to write SQL directly in SQL Server and get the results. Another way is to use Python to run the calculation and push the result back to the database.

Coding is not important here but I attached the code I wrote in SQL server. At least it shows that SQL allows me to do complex calculation. I know Python can also do this without any issue. So what I am struggling is which way is the best in terms of calculating ratios/metrics, SQL script or Python? My guess is that Python has better performance but by writing SQL you don't need to worry about data connection issue as you can just use it inside the database. Also you can leverage the features inside database tool, for instance, setting up trigger inside the database so it knows when to run specific functions.

Any thoughts are welcome and thanks a lot in advance!

Below is an example of calculating Debt to Equity using SQL:

```
Create View View_Calc_DebtToEquity
As

with TotalLiabilitiesToEquity(TotalLiabilities,TotalEquity,TotalLiabilitiesTTM,   
TotalEquityTTM, DebtToEquity_Target, CompanyName, AnalysisName,   
CurrentYear, TheMonth)
As (
Select TotalLiabilities=Max(Case when CategoryDesc='Total   
Liabilities' and Rowtype='Type Total' and Statement='Balance Sheet'
then ActualAmount else Null end),
TotalEquity=Max(Case when CategoryDesc='Total Equity' and   
Rowtype='Total' and Statement='Balance Sheet' then ActualAmount
else Null end),
TotalLiabilitiesTTM=Max(Case when CategoryDesc='Total Liabilities'   
and Rowtype='Type Total' and Statement='Balance Sheet' then ActualTTM
else Null end),
TotalEquityTTM=Max(Case when CategoryDesc='Total Equity' and   
Rowtype='Total' and Statement='Balance Sheet' then ActualTTM
else Null end),
DebtToEquity_Target=Max(Case when CategoryDesc='Debt to   
Equity_Target' and Rowtype='Category' and Statement='Nonfinancial'   
then ActualAmount else Null end),
CompanyName, AnalysisName, CurrentYear, TheMonth
From dbo.DashboardFinalOutput
Group by CompanyName, AnalysisName, CurrentYear, TheMonth)

Select CategoryDesc='Debt to Equity',
   TheMTD=TotalLiabilities/nullif(TotalEquity,0),
   TheTTM=TotalLiabilitiesTTM/nullif(TotalEquityTTM,0),
   TheTarget=DebtToEquity_Target,
   CompanyName,AnalysisName,CurrentYear,TheMonth

From TotalLiabilitiesToEquity
```

Comment: IUCC every usecase is different and each has its pros and cons. Both should work but it really depends on the usecase and tradeoff. If you have manageable data you can use python alone that might be faster in some cases but it is not a general rule of thumb. I think you should try both and pick which works best for you for your usecase.

Comment: Can you please format and indent your SQL. It is completely unreadable like this.

Answer (score 0):

What the best approach is depends on the context you're operating in. Are you constrained by runtime resources in such a way that you need to find the most performant way?

Also think outside of the operation itself - which language is more popular within your organization? Will anyone else be able to understand what it does? Which is more readable/auditable?